# C - while(true) vs while(condition) - performance

Tags: c

I would like to know if there is a difference in performance between :

```
while(true)
{
.....
}
```

And :

```
bool x;
x = true;
while(x)
{
.....
}
```

I need the best performance and a small difference between the two is important to my application.

Info from comment by OP:
The `while(true)` will at some point also be left, that is however rare.

Comment: First of all, don't fall into the trap of premature optimization. Secondly, *meassure*! With an optimized build. And look at the generated code (with optimization) to compare.

Comment: It will depend on your compiler and if you use `x` later. If you never use `x` mostly (maybe every) compiler will do the same for both.

Comment: I agree with @Someprogrammerdude. Apart from that, if the loop runs forever, why do you care about an advantage of a few cycles at the start?

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow if the loop body does very little, it can make quite a difference. One instruction less, if no test is made.

Comment: Do you need an endless loop? Then why use a condition? If you need a loop which can be left, then your `while(true){...}` will contain an `if(!x)` which your `while(x)` does not contain. Any potential optimisation benefit of `while(true)` over `while(x)` will be lost at that point.

Comment: Yunnosch, you are right. For my application, I need to be able to get outside of the loop. But getting outside of the loop is not a "normal runtime behavior", it happens only very rarely. That's why I want it to not interfere with my performance.

Comment: That is what I mean. leaving might be rare, but checking whether it is time to leave while be in each loop.

Comment: Go on, tells us, what is in the loop?   I mean, typically, such loops contain system calls which ,as others have said, would make your 'optimization' pointless.

Comment: 1. Compilers are smart nowadays, they take care of this kind of optimization themselves. 2. If your loop contains more than 2 or 3 instructions, the difference will be most likely non mesurable anyway.

Comment: The loop must be optimized and so does not contains any system calls.

Comment: Yeah - the compiiler will just put in a jump back to the start in both cases.

Comment: OK, by this point, I'm assuming an embedded system and you are continually polling an I/O device?  Probably with interrupts disabled?   Use hand-crafted assembler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a truly endless loop, then why use a condition?
If you need a loop which can be left, then your `while(true){...}` will contain an `if(!x)` which your `while(x)` does not contain.
Any potential optimisation benefit of `while(true)` over `while(x)` will be lost at that point.

Comment: If the condition in the `while(x)` has any meaning (and OP has confirmed that) then each turn of the loop inside `while(true)` will at some point check the same condition, inverted for determining when to leave the loop. I.e. `if(!x)`, followed by things I don't like, e.g. `break` or `goto`. Not liking those things for me is another reason for using `while(x)` but strictly speaking not relevant for OPs question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all...
If you want to make an infinite loop you (always) use:

```
while(true)
{
  ...
}
```

There would be absolutely no reason why defining a variable before that loop should speed up your "application". So there is no reason to use:

```
bool x = true;
while(x)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for making an answer. Would you like to show your badge for taking the [tour]? Most people with the privilege to upvote answers like to see that badge on an answerer account.